# Minha função só retorna None

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estava criando/tentando criar um chat bot python, até ai tudo bem. Porém quando uso minha função que retorna a resposta do robô ele retorna None! Eu não sei resolver...

```
def responder(conversa1, posicao): #conversa1 significa o que o usuário digitou. A posição esta definida como 1 por padrão 
   a = open('conversas.txt', 'r')
   for linha in a.readlines():
      if conversa1 == linha:
        resultado = linha
        res = resultado.split('= ')[posicao].strip('\n')
        return res
```

Importante dizer que as respostas estão salvas em um arquivo txt

```
oi=  oi tudo bem?
ola= ola para voce tambem
tudo bem?= tudo bem sim, e voce?
tudo= que legal
```

OBS: no if já tentei substituir o "==" por "in" mas quando eu faço isso ele mostra a resposta do robô errada, não sei o porque.

Answer (score 0):

A indentação do seu código está errada. O `IF` deve estar dentro do seu for.
O `None` estava sendo retornado pois o `IF` nunca fora executado.
NO caso o IN só funcionaria se sua linha fosse do tipo `LISTA`, o que não é, se você está comparando duas strings o correto é usar `==`.

```
def responder(conversa1, posicao):
   a = open('conversas.txt', 'r')
   for linha in a.readlines():
       if conversa1 == linha:
         resultado = linha
         res = resultado.split('= ')[posicao].strip('\n')
         return res
    return 'conversa1 nao eh igual a linha'
```

Comment: Oi, acabei de fazer isso (colocar o if dentro do for) no meu código e o erro persiste

Comment: fora do for coloque um return 'conversa1 é diferente de linha'

Comment: @Rcoletto alterei a resposta para voce testar novamente.

Comment: Acabei de colocar o return 'conversa1 nao eh igual a linha' e agora ele só me retorna isso.

Comment: Exatamente o problema está no IF conversa1 == linha, use uma ferramenta de debugger para ver os valores de cada variável e verá que realmente são diferentes.

Comment: O que eu faço nesse caso? Eu debugo o código mas isso  não iria resolver certo?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tens a solução e com [context manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/). O problema estava neste if **if conversa1 == linha.strip('\n')**:

```
def responder(conversa1, posicao):
   with open('conversas.txt', 'r') as a:    
     for linha in a.readlines():
         if conversa1 == linha.strip('\n'):
           resultado = linha
           res = resultado.split('= ')[posicao].strip('\n')
           return res
   return 'conversa1 nao eh igual a linha'
```

Comment: Acabei de ler o artigo que você colocou ali em cima e mesmo assim não consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: O link é sobre gestão de contexto, abrir ficheiros de disco, por exemplo. A minha função de resposta, testaste?

Comment: Testei e continua dando problema

Comment: Deixa claro ou explica bem, com base no teu ficheiro de source, e pela frase de input qual o resultado esperado.

Comment: Ou seja, qual o conteudo do teu ficheiro e qual o input que estás a testar e qual deveria ser o resultado.